# How to fix this fixed navigation bar fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a fixed navigation bar. I want the initial menu to not be displayed only after u scroll the page to a certain position. I did thaa working but then when i scroll back on top the menu which initial is not displayed appears. I have the class in css defined as display none. Can u help me with this? Thnx in advance.

```
$(function(){

    var menu = $('#menu'),
        pos = menu.offset();

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(this).scrollTop() > pos.top+menu.height() && menu.hasClass('default')){
                menu.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('default').addClass('fixed').fadeIn('fast');
                });
            } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= pos.top && menu.hasClass('fixed')){
                menu.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('default').fadeIn('fast');
                });
            }
        });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VjfHg/

**EDIT:** Hey, thanks for all your answers, all are working, sorry if i'm to bold but could you help me with displaying it to a certain position let's say after u scroll 500px and then fade out at the same position?:)

Comment: Just remove the last fadeIn()
http://jsfiddle.net/Pallab/VjfHg/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify your `else` loop like below (to use `fadeOut`):

`fadeIn` *displays the matched elements* by fading them to opaque whereas `fadeOut` *hides the matched elements* by fading them to transparent.

```
else if($(this).scrollTop() <= pos.top && menu.hasClass('fixed')){
                menu.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('default').fadeOut('fast');
                });
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/VjfHg/6/)

**EDIT:** [**Updated Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/VjfHg/8/) based on the change in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
else if($(this).scrollTop() <= pos.top && menu.hasClass('fixed')){
            menu.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                $(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('default').fadeOut('fast');
            });
        }
```

Instead of fadeIn use fadeOut

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this to happen is this line

```
$(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('default').fadeIn('fast');
```

After you add the class 'default' you use the *fadeIn* function . jQuery detects that the fadeIn effect is being applied to a element which has `display:none` and adds a new CSS style to that div which is `display: block`

There are 2 ways to resolve this.

***Jquery Way***

Change

```
$(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('default').fadeIn('fast');
                          TO 
$(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('default');
```

**[jQuery Way Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/VjfHg/7/)**

***CSS Way***

Change following line in your .default class.

```
display:none; 
     TO
display:none !important;
```

[**CSS Way Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/VjfHg/5/)